# Is it possible to avoid microphone voices when screen recording?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, audiokit, avaudioengine

I want to record screen audio with permission for audio processing "Input.installTap" type of code definitely works for me but I want to eliminate outside voices like the human voice or background noises. I think if I stop to microphone it might be work but, I couldn't find any answer yet.

is it possible with anything?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [ReplayKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit) and disabling the microphone?? (available in iOS already, and I believe macOS from 11.0+).

Check out also the [WWDC Big Sur Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/recording_and_streaming_your_macos_app).

Comment: Actually, I considered I just need a recorded voice but when I tap to record button Replay kit ask "Do you give permission to record screen?" etc. I don't want that. Are there any solutions for asking only once? or make a custom permission screen?